# Django management command extract common functionality by using a superclass

Tags: python, django

I have two similar management commands, with lot of common code. I want to put common code in a MyClass that extends NoArgsCommand and then create commands let us say CommandA and CommandB that extend MyClass. I have a handle method in CommandA and CommandB and trying to call super.handle. I am getting error type object 'super' has no attribute 'handle'

Comment: post your code please. and your command that throw the error.

Comment: Are you on Python2 or Python3? How do you call your super from CommandA and from MyClass?

Answer (score 1):

Valid python [syntax for calling super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) is:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    super(CommandA, self).handle(*args, **options)
```

If you use python 3 then you can omit [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) arguments:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    super().handle(*args, **options)
```